# How do I limit access to a port of a docker container with iptables?

Tags: vpn, iptables, docker

I have a docker host running a container on a bridged network, providing vpn access to a endpoint on multiple ports (one for each system on the remote network). Now i want to limit the access to that vpn connection to a single ip.

My ip: 192.168.0.10

Container Ports: 1000, 1001 (3398, 3340 on the host)

What i've tried among other things

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.10 --dport 1000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.10 --dport 1000 -j ACCEPT
```

Now whatever constellation i tried, either every one or no one can establish a connection. Or the container seems to establish the vpn session but being unable to reach the remote system.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?